# Multiple group - Averaging of each value inside array without duplicity from another document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have added three JSON sample data for better understanding:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b961bdfd6588fed3fd8e2a9"),
    "claim" : ObjectId("5b927bd9c725181a3dc9107e"),
    "user" : ObjectId("5b869a5d0d56de9d788edb7e"),
    "comprisedPhrase" : [
        {
            "phrase" : "ABC",
            "like" : 1,
            "dislike" : 0
        }, 
        {
            "phrase" : "DEF",
            "like" : 0,
            "dislike" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "phrase" : "GHI",
            "like" : 1,
            "dislike" : 0
        }
    ], 
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b961bdfd6588fed3fd8e2a9"),
    "claim" : ObjectId("5b927bd9c725181a3dc9107e"),
    "user" : ObjectId("5b869a5d0d56de9d788edb7a”),
    "comprisedPhrase" : [
        {
            "phrase" : "ABC",
            "like" : 1,
            "dislike" : 0
        }, 
        {
            "phrase" : "DEF",
            "like" : 0,
            "dislike" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "phrase" : "GHI",
            "like" : 1,
            "dislike" : 0
        }
    ], 
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b961bdfd6588fed3fd8e2a9"),
    "claim" : ObjectId("5b927bd9c725181a3dc9107a”),
    "user" : ObjectId("5b869a5d0d56de9d788edb7a”),
    "comprisedPhrase" : [
        {
            "phrase" : "ABC",
            "like" : 0,
            "dislike" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "phrase" : "DEF",
            "like" : 1,
            "dislike" : 0
        }, 
        {
            "phrase" : "GHI",
            "like" : 1,
            "dislike" : 0
        },
        {
            "phrase" : "JKL",
            "like" : 0,
            "dislike" : 0
        }
    ], 
}
```

Expected output:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b927bd9c725181a3dc9107e"), // Claim id
    "comprisedPhrase" : [ 
        {
            "phrase" : "ABC",
            "totalCount" : 2.0,
            "sumLike" : 2,
            "sumDislike" : 0
        }, 
        {
            "phrase" : "DEF",
            "totalCount" : 2.0,
            "sumLike" : 0,
            "sumDislike" : 2
        },
        {
            "phrase" : "GHI",
            "totalCount" : 2.0,
            "sumLike" : 2,
            "sumDislike" : 0
        }
    ],
    "totalCount" : 2.0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b927bd9c725181a3dc9107a"),
    "comprisedPhrase" : [ 
        {
            "phrase" : "ABC",
            "totalCount" : 1.0,
            "sumLike" : 0,
            "sumDislike" : 1
        },
        {
            "phrase" : "DEF",
            "totalCount" : 1.0,
            "sumLike" : 1,
            "sumDislike" : 0
        },
        {
            "phrase" : "GHI",
            "totalCount" : 1.0,
            "sumLike" : 1,
            "sumDislike" : 0
        },
        {
            "phrase" : "JKL",
            "totalCount" : 1.0,
            "sumLike" : 0,
            "sumDislike" : 0
        }
    ],
    "totalCount" : 1.0
}
```

What, I have tried So far:

```
db.getCollection(‘anydb’).aggregate([{
  {
    "$unwind": "$comprisedPhrase"
  },
  {
      "$group" : {
        _id: "$comprisedPhrase.phrase",
        claimId: { "$first" : "$claim._id"},
        totalCount: { "$sum": 1 },
        sumLike : {"$sum" : "$comprisedPhrase.like"},
        sumDislike : {"$sum" : "$comprisedPhrase.dislike"}
    }
  },{
      "$group" : {
        _id: "$claimId",
        comprisedPhrase: { "$push" : { phrase: "$_id", totalCount: "$totalCount", sumLike: "$sumLike", sumDislike: "$sumDislike" }},
        totalCount: { "$sum": 1 }
    }
  }
  ])
```

But, this will count ABC from different claims too. And it is obvious.

I just want to group By `claim` id. and for each claim, there is the list of words. Those list of words should give me the sum of `like` and `dislike` or averaging the `like` and `dislike` with inside `totalCount`.

***Note: MongoDB V3.2.18***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$comprisedPhrase" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": { "phrase": "$comprisedPhrase.phrase", "claimId": "$claim" },
    "sumLike": { "$sum": "$comprisedPhrase.like" },
    "sumDislike": { "$sum": "$comprisedPhrase.dislike" },
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id.claimId",
    "totalCount": { "$first": "$count" },
    "comprisedPhrase": {
      "$push": {
        "phrase": "$_id.phrase",
        "sumLike": "$sumLike",
        "sumDislike": "$sumDislike",
        "totalCount": "$count"
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Comment: Thank you. That was very close. But, how can I replace root with this result? You can see my expected output.

Comment: What I have done, unwind the object and again group to match with my expected output. Are there any other parameters by which I can do the same?

Comment: But the output is same as you posted above in the question. Isn't it?

Comment: Check above update, I have added here only some part of aggregation before.

Answer (score 0):

Your second stage should make _id as both `$comprisedPhrase.phrase` and `$claim._id`.

So the final query should look like this:

```
db.getCollection(‘anydb’).aggregate([{
  {
    "$unwind": "$comprisedPhrase"
  },
  {
      "$group" : {
        _id: {"phrase": "$comprisedPhrase.phrase", "claimId":"$claim._id"},
        //claimId: { "$first" : "$claim._id"},
        totalCount: { "$sum": 1 },
        sumLike : {"$sum" : "$comprisedPhrase.like"},
        sumDislike : {"$sum" : "$comprisedPhrase.dislike"}
    }
  },{
      "$group" : {
        _id: "$_id.claimId",
        comprisedPhrase: { "$push" : { phrase: "$_id.phrase", totalCount: "$totalCount", sumLike: "$sumLike", sumDislike: "$sumDislike" }},
        totalCount: { "$sum": 1 }
    }
  }
  ])
```

Hope this helps. Thanks.